# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen header image size not responsive for mobile

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images, css, headers

I'm currently working on a website in wordpress. I've been struggling with this problem for a while. At the first the header image was too big even for computer. I managed to make it shorter using some extra css. However now it is broken for mobile. I've included a picture and a link to the website. This is what it looks like on mobile. It should be way shorter and also some kind of shadow is shown. [Here is a link to the website.](https://rnltrading.com) [image: This is what it looks like on mobile, testing with the element inspect.]

The code below is the code I'm using to shorten the image for visitors on pc.

```
.twentyseventeen-front-page.has-header-image .custom-header-media, .twentyseventeen-front-page.has-header-video .custom-header-media, .home.blog.has-header-image .custom-header-media, .home.blog.has-header-video .custom-header-media {
height: 50vh;}
```

Regards Luuc

Comment: If you're never going to see the top part of the image anywhere, and it would fix this problem, why not crop it in a graphics program?

Comment: I am however going to see the top. I'm afraid that when i edit the photo it could cause problems further on. Also i think the recommended header image size for the theme is 2000 x 1200 px. I would rather not change that unless it is the only way.